# iOS client app with Mac server

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, client-server

I am attempting to build a client/server game architecture and would like to begin testing the game using my local Mac as the server.  I have found several articles on Bonjour, but that is for local network traffic only.  My goal is to make this application work over the Internet, connecting to a hosted application on a static address to facilitate turn data.  However, I'm at a loss as to which Cocoa APIs to use for this purpose.  Should I use `NSConnection`, `NSStream subclasses`, or good 'ol C `sockets` and whatnot.  The game state is already built in Objective-C and is ready to be set in motion once I have the server facilities ready.  Any insight?

Comment: You might also be interested in https://bitbucket.org/snej/mynetwork/wiki/Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use sockets, since they're not hard to use and are a standard way. I've even written an asynchronous wrapper class around BSD sockets: https://github.com/H2CO3/TCPHelper

This is for simple, one-to-one TCP protocol connections, supporting both IPv4 and IPv6. You can send and receive raw NSData and possibly build a protocol around it.

Foundation classes such as NSURLConnection are not particularily for this purpose; rather than to interact with standard HTTP servers (I suppose you don't want to implement a full HTTP server for a game).

NSNetServices may suit you just like CFNetwork, but the latter is a bit harder to use. If you'd like to use Foundation classes, I'd recommend NSNetServices.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

NSConnection, NSStrean and C sockets are build for different needs. You need to specify the needs of your game and the kind of service in order to get more help. If you want to develop a client-server application that relies on the Internet and not on the local network, Bonjour will not be able to help.

C sockets, and Cocoa APIs that wrap around them are intended to operate on an open network stream between the client and the server. The advantage of having an open stream is that you can have the server send data to the client without the client having requested for it. NSURLConnection in Cocoa works differently. With it, you can perform HTTP requests and receive formatted responses from a server.

If your application is based on HTTP requests, I recommend you take a look an NSURLConnection, or AFNetworking, as a 3rd party alternative. If your application relies on open streams, I recommend you take a look at CFNetwork from Apple (C wrapper around BSD sockets that originates from the days Macs had Carbon, with great performance, stability and versatility) and GCDAsyncSocket, a 3rd party library wrapped around BSD Sockets, supports Crand Central Dispatch, is Objective-C ready, and does the job wonderfully.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to accomplish this.  It really depends on how you'll be passing the data and what it will be used for.

First, I would setup a hostname that you can use for development purposes with your game. You can use anything like http://dyn.com/dns/ to setup this for your Mac.  Then you can enable a compiler setting to switch out the development / production URL's.

Next, I would recommend using TCP sockets for your game (using CocoaAsyncSocket - https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).  This method should work fine your your use case.  Since you are doing turn-based data (and since all of that data is vital) I would not recommend using UDP sockets (but those would work if you were solely passing position, video, or audio data where a dropped packet might not matter).